# What does the following Regex evaluates

Tags: javascript, regex

How can we interpret the following regex?

`/^\/products\/(?:([^\/]+?))(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/?$/i,`

I understand it to evaluate something like

`/products/ (optional parameters)`

Note: I am programming in Javascript. Node framework to be precise.

Comment: There are various different flavours of regex.  So when asking a question like this it is helpful if you provide some context, such as specifying the language e.g. perl

Comment: I am programming in Javascript. Node framework to be precise.

Comment: For future reference, you can *edit* your question.  So please add any useful information to the question, and use comments for transient conversation or side issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/^\/products\/(?:([^\/]+?))(?:\/([^\/]+?))?\/?$/i,`

The first `/` is a regex delimiter. `^` refers to the beginning of a string `/products/`

`(?:` Do not capture group

`([^\/]+?)` capture to \1, any string of characters except `\/`. This string of characters is 'least selected because of the trailing `?` in the end. ')` ends non-capture group.

`(?:` Another do-not-capture group begins, it groups but does not capture `/` because of escape character `\/`.

`([^\/]+?)` capture to \2, any string of characters except `\/`. This string of characters is 'least selected because of the trailing `?` in the end. ')` ends non-capture group.

Not sure the `?` at the end of `(?:([^\/]+?))(?:\/([^\/]+?))` makes any difference.

`\/?` looks for an optinal `/`

`$`    before an optional \n, and the end of the string

`/i` makes the regexp ignore case, so it will match `/products/`, `/PROducts' etc. in the beginning.

Comment: ([^\/]+?) capture to \1, any string of characters except \/... incorrect. /. \ is an escape char